# regexp_substr skips over empty positions

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

With this code to return the nth value in a pipe delimited string...

```
regexp_substr(int_record.interfaceline, '[^|]+', 1, i)
```

it works fine when all values are present

`Mike|Male|Yes|20000|Yes` so the `3rd` value is `Yes` (correct)

but if the string is

`Mike|Male||20000|Yes`, the 3rd value is `20000` (not what I want)

How can I tell the expression to not skip over the empty values?

TIA

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This should be the best solution for you.

```
SELECT
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes',
                    '^([^|]*\|){2}([^|]*).*$',
                    '\2' )
          TEXT
FROM
      DUAL;
```

So for your problem

```
SELECT
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( INCOMINGSTREAMOFSTRINGS,
                    '^([^|]*\|){N-1}([^|]*).*$',
                    '\2' )
          TEXT
FROM
      DUAL;
```

--INCOMINGSTREAMOFSTRINGS is your complete string with delimiter

--You should pass n-1 to obtain nth position

ALTERNATE 2:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes' X FROM DUAL)
SELECT
      X,
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( X,
                    '^([^|]*).*$',
                    '\1' )
          Y1,
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( X,
                    '^[^|]*\|([^|]*).*$',
                    '\1' )
          Y2,
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( X,
                    '^([^|]*\|){2}([^|]*).*$',
                    '\2' )
          Y3,
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( X,
                    '^([^|]*\|){3}([^|]*).*$',
                    '\2' )
          Y4,
      REGEXP_REPLACE ( X,
                    '^([^|]*\|){4}([^|]*).*$',
                    '\2' )
          Y5
FROM
      T;
```

ALTERNATE 3:

```
SELECT
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes',
                                '\|',
                                ';' ),
                   '(^|;)([^;]*)',
                   1,
                   1,
                   NULL,
                   2 )
          AS FIRST,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes',
                                '\|',
                                ';' ),
                   '(^|;)([^;]*)',
                   1,
                   2,
                   NULL,
                   2 )
          AS SECOND,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes',
                                '\|',
                                ';' ),
                   '(^|;)([^;]*)',
                   1,
                   3,
                   NULL,
                   2 )
          AS THIRD,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes',
                                '\|',
                                ';' ),
                   '(^|;)([^;]*)',
                   1,
                   4,
                   NULL,
                   2 )
          AS FOURTH,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes',
                                '\|',
                                ';' ),
                   '(^|;)([^;]*)',
                   1,
                   5,
                   NULL,
                   2 )
          AS FIFTH
FROM
      DUAL;
```

Comment: Please edit existing answers, do not create multiple answers.

Comment: @realspirituals - this worked a treat. Thanks so much for your time (and thanks everyone else for taking the time too). Much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

The regexp_substr works this way:

> If occurrence is greater than 1, then **the database searches for the
>   second occurrence beginning with the first character following the
>   first occurrence of pattern**, and so forth. This behavior is different
>   from the SUBSTR function, which begins its search for the second
>   occurrence at the second character of the first occurrence.

So the pattern [^|] will look for NON pipes, meaning it will skip consecutive pipes ("||") looking for a non-pipe char.

You might try:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(replace('A|test||string', '|', '| '), '[^|]+', 1, 4)) from dual;
```

This will replace a "|" with a "| " and allow you to match based on the pattern [^|]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a CSV file thus my separator was the semicolon (`;`)
So I started with an expression like the following one:

```
 select regexp_substr(';2;;4;', '[^;]+', 1, i) from dual
```

letting `i` iterate from 1 to 5.

And of course it didn't work either.

To get the empty parts I just say they could be at the beginning (`^;`), or in the middle (`;;`) or at the end (`;$`). And or-ing all of this together gives:

```
select regexp_substr(';2;;4;', '[^;]+|^;|;;|;$', 1, i) from dual
```

And believe me or not: testing for `i` from 1 to 5 it works!

But let's not forgot the last details: with this approach you get ; for fields that are empty originally. 
The next lines are showing how to get rid of them easily replacing them by empty strings(nulls):

with stage1 as (

select regexp_substr(';2;;4;', '[^;]+|^;|;;|;$', 1, 2) as F from dual

)

select case when F like '%;' then '' else F end from stage1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
with l as (select 'Mike|Male||20000|Yes' str from dual)
select regexp_substr(str,'(".*"|[^|]*)(\||$)',1,level,null,1) 
from dual,l 
where level=3/*use any position*/ connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'([^|]*)(\||$)')
```

Answer (score 0):

As an complement to @tbone response...

Oddly, my oracle didn't recognize the blank space character in this list: `[^|]`
In this cases can be confusing and hard to realize what is going wrong. 
Try with this regex `([^|]| )+`. Also, to detect a posible first blank item, it is better to replace the separator with the space blank before, and not after it:
`' |'`

```
trim(regexp_substr(replace('A|test||string', '|', ' |'), '([^|]| )+', 1, 4))
```