# REGEXP_SUBSTR doesn't work when have blank value between string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Wonder how to rewrite `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function should it can return correct value for

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('110001,|A1|1|||||N,A1,1,,,,,N,2T BBA HF LOW COST,HOME FINANCING-i',
                     '[^,]+', 
                      1, 
                      11) 
 from dual
```

expected result: HOME FINANCING-i

Comment: `regexp_substr(regexp_replace(col, '(.*?,){10}'), '[^,]*')`

Comment: Duplicate of [regex substr skips over empty positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919341/regexp-substr-skips-over-empty-positions/18921549)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your pattern to match the *emptiness* between two commas `([^,]*)(,|$)`:

```
with t1(col) as(
  select '110001,|A1|1|||||N,A1,1,,,,,N,2T BBA HF LOW COST,HOME FINANCING-i'
    from dual
)
select regexp_substr(col, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 11, 'i', 1) as res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
RES            
----------------
HOME FINANCING-i
```

Comment: this will work for last position, but in other position example select regexp_substr(col, '([^,])*(,|$)', 1, 1) will return 110001, how to remove ',' ?